# Как ускорить загрузку ListView (приблизительно 2500 строк)?

Tags: java, listview

Очень долго загружается Listview. Как можно это ускорить?

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document doc;
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://Сайт").maxBodySize(0).get();
            content = doc.select("tr");

            titleList.clear();

            for (Element contents : content) {
                titleList.add(contents.text());
                publishProgress(progress);
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: разбить на несколько ListView?

Comment: Уточните, что именно происходит долго - загрузка данных с сервера? Или парсинг данных? Или добавление данных в ListView? Обязательно нужно сразу 2500 элементов добавить в ListView? Пользователь все равно их не просмотрит все сразу, добавляйте по мере необходимости. Можно загрузку данных с сервера и добавление их в локальную базу данных вынести в отдельный сервис, или как у вас в AsynkTask сделать, а в ListView подгружать данные из вашей БД, по мере того как пользователь будет скроллить.

Comment: Получается, что на разных устройствах разное время загрузки .У кого-то  загружается быстрее, у кого-то дольше.Я не могу понять зависит ли это от версии Android, или от мощности процессора.(Мне кажется в моем случае интернет здесь не причём)