# Что значит : в цикле for ? Простыми словами)

Tags: for

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect("https://Сайт").maxBodySize(0).get();
            content = doc.select("tr");

            titleList.clear();

            for (Element contents : content) {
                titleList.add(contents.text());
                publishProgress(progress);
            }
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, что за язык вы используете...

Comment: Поштучно перебираете массив `content`, и для каждого его элемента вызываете пару команд в теле цикла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм, особенность синтаксиса. У вас есть некий список/контейнер/массив, и вам нужно пройтись по его элементам. Вы пишете for(текущий элемент : cписок), и таким образом, в каждой итерации цикла переменная стоящая до **":"** принимает значение очередного элемента из указанного после **":"** контейнера..

Comment: ":" - это синтаксис который обозначает деление?

Comment: @Дмитрий В данном случае этот символ просто отделяет переменную в которую записывается очередное значение из контейнера от переменной самого контейнера. Таков синтаксис языка, таковы правила..

Comment: Хорошо ,  а при каком условии  for остановится?

Comment: @Дмитрий Когда дойдет до последнего элемента контейнера, то есть, когда переберет все что там есть..

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо ,если вам не сложно можете взглянуть ещё на этот вопрос! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933486/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-listview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-2500-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82

Answer (score 0):

это `foreach`, пробегает по коллекции и достаёт один элемент в каждой итерации